# How to remove multiple references when removing many documents?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm removing a document from collection 'Component' to which there are references in collection 'Space'.

Upon removal of document from Component, I remove the reference to that document from Space.

There is another collection 'ListItem', to which there are references in 'Space'. As I delete the Component, I want to delete an unknown amount of documents from 'ListItem' and then delete all these references from 'Space'. I was able to delete the documents inside 'ListItem' but not the references in Space.

I couldn't figure out how to use hooks with this. I now understand this would only work for removing a single reference. If I could somehow, per instance of ListItem that gets removed, pull ListItem.ListId from Space.listItems, it might work? $pullAll seems to be the most promising potential solution I've found thus far. Then I'd have to query Space and find all matching ids from Space.listItems and store them in an array?

```
ListItemsSchema.pre('deleteMany', function(next) {
    var list = this;
    var id = this.ListId;
    var spaceId = this.SpaceId;

    list.model('Space').update(
        { _id: spaceId},
        {$pull: {listItems: id}},
        {multi: true},
        next
    );
    // i'm removing ListItem.ListId from Space.listItems
})
```

I couldn't figure out how to solve it as I remove the ListItems. Same issue that the pull method is wrong.

```
router.delete('/DeleteComponent/:id', function(req, res) {

    let id = req.params.id;
    let spaceID = req.body.CurrentSpaceId;
    let listArray = [];

    Component.findOneAndRemove({ _id: id}).exec(function(err, removed) {
        Space.findOneAndUpdate(
            { _id: spaceID },
            { $pull: {components: id} },
            { new: true },
            function(err, removedFromSpace) {
                if (err) { console.log(err) }
                res.status(200).send(removedFromSpace);
            })
    });

    // delete all items where id == component/list id
    ListItem.deleteMany({ ListId: id}).exec(function(err, results) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log("ListItems successfully removed.", results);
        }

        Space.update(
            { _id: spaceID},
            {$pull: {listItems: id}},
            {multi: true},
            function(err, removedFromSpace) {
                if (err) { console.log(err) }
                res.status(200).send(removedFromSpace);
            }
        );

    });
});
```

I've tried a few more things but these have been my best attempts so far.

**Space's schema:**

```
let spaceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  components: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Component'}],
  listItems: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'ListItem'}],
});
```

**Component's schema:**

```
let componentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    ...
})
```

**ListItem's schema:**

```
let ListItemsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    ListItem: String,
    // ListId is equivalent to Component's _id
    ListId: String,
    SpaceId: String
});
```

Expected result is that when a component is deleted, then also ListItems are deleted along with references to them in Space. Currently I'm unable to do the last step of deleting the references for ListItems in Space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving the problem through making structural changes to the database schemas, ending up with a generally cleaner and more elegant solution.

I moved the references `listItems: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'ListItem'}]` to the `componentSchema`, so when a component is deleted, all the references to associated `ListItem` documents are also deleted, without having to worry about accessing `Space` or iterating over values to dynamically create arrays. After that, all `ListItem` documents where `ListItem.ComponentId` matches the id of the recently deleted component are deleted.

```
// Delete component and remove from Spaces
router.delete('/DeleteComponent/:id', function(req, res) {

    let id = req.params.id;
    let spaceID = req.body.CurrentSpaceId;

    Component.findOneAndRemove({ _id: id}).exec(function(err, removed) {
        Space.findOneAndUpdate(
            { _id: spaceID },
            { $pull: {components: id} },
            { new: true },
            function(err, removedFromSpace) {
                if (err) { console.log(err) }
                res.status(200).send(removedFromSpace);
            })
    });

    // delete all items where id == component id
    ListItem.deleteMany({ ComponentId: id}).exec(function(err, results) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log("ListItems successfully removed.", results);
        }

    });
});
```

I did make progress towards solving the original technical challenge as well. My suggestion would be to find a way to gather all the IDs you want to remove from a reference and put them in an array, and then you can use [$pullAll](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pullAll/) to remove them from references:

```
let myIdsArray = [id1, id2, id3];
Collection.update( {_id: id}, { $pullAll: {field: myIdsArray } } );
```

However, as far as I can tell, unless you have a very good reason for your references to exist in such a disconnected way, it makes more sense to use the much simpler solution, especially when using MongoDB or any other non-relational database.